# Subquery for MAX() value from LeftJoin

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this query in SQL Server, and i would like to know if it can be shorter ?

i've made a subquery (with a group by) with all the column just to get the MAX() value of 3 dates which come from a table left join.

Ithink i can't do without a subquery to get the MAX() of the 3 dates.

```
SELECT otherCol1
    ,otherCol2 
    ,MAX(UnsubscribedDate) AS UnsubscribedDate
    ,MAX(OpenedDate) AS OpenedDate
    ,MAX(ClickedDate) AS ClickedDate
FROM (
    SELECT otherCol1
        ,otherCol2
        ,tu.JoinDate AS UnsubscribedDate
        ,trkOp.Clicktime AS OpenedDate
        ,trkRes.Clicktime AS ClickedDate
    FROM v_members_email_occurrence vmec
    LEFT JOIN tracking_unsubscribed tu WITH (NOLOCK) ON tu.ReportId = vmec.SendingId
    LEFT JOIN tracking_opened trkOp WITH (NOLOCK) ON trkOp.ReportId = vmec.SendingId
    LEFT JOIN tracking_result trkRes WITH (NOLOCK) ON trkRes.ReportId = vmec.SendingId
    WHERE vmec.MemberId = @MemberId
    ) AS Result
GROUP BY otherCol1
        ,otherCol2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate without a subquery:

```
SELECT otherCol1
    ,otherCol2
    ,MAX(tu.JoinDate) AS UnsubscribedDate
    ,MAX(trkOp.Clicktime) AS OpenedDate
    ,MAX(trkRes.Clicktime) AS ClickedDate
FROM v_members_email_occurrence vmec
LEFT JOIN tracking_unsubscribed tu WITH (NOLOCK) ON tu.ReportId = vmec.SendingId
LEFT JOIN tracking_opened trkOp WITH (NOLOCK) ON trkOp.ReportId = vmec.SendingId
LEFT JOIN tracking_result trkRes WITH (NOLOCK) ON trkRes.ReportId = vmec.SendingId
WHERE vmec.MemberId = @MemberId
GROUP BY otherCol1
        ,otherCol2
```